# Check if the value is empty

Tags: jquery

How is the "check" made for this to check if a textfield is empty?

Jquery:

```
$("#AddGoogleMap").click(function () {      
    if($('#googleMapCity').val()==null) {
        alert("You need to fill out a city");
    } else {
     // do something
    }
```

Comment: `$('#googleMapCity').val()===''` or `$('#googleMapCity').val().length===0`

Comment: Did you search ? I can't think the question I linked or similar ones wasn't listed when you typed your question.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: `.empty()` removes the content and any nested DOM element.

Comment: @kiddorails Sorry ^^'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string and then compare the value with the empty string, like:

```
if( $.trim($('#googleMapCity').val()) === '') {
     alert("You need to fill out a city");
} else {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting best practice of trimming in case of empty space

Comment: Nice! Thanks! But the thing is it fires even though I fill out something in the field, does it need to be a rule for the "else"?

Comment: @Kim: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBQCD/) might help you! Try it once.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#googleMapCity').val() === "") {
 alert("You need to fill out a city");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be done like this:

```
if($.trim($('#googleMapCity').val())==="")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#AddGoogleMap").click(function () {      
    if($('#googleMapCity').val()==='') {
    alert('You need to fill out a city');

     } else {
     // do something
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NpvNy/)

```
$("#AddGoogleMap").click(function () {      
    if($('#googleMapCity').val() === "") {
        alert("You need to fill out a city");
     } else {
     // do something
     }
});
```